# Testing unicode grapheme cluster equality in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

A unicode character like 'é' can be represented as a UTF16 string (Dart's native implementation) in two ways:

1. '\u00e9'
2. '\u0065\u0301' (e + combining diacritical mark)

Since they are internally different, testing for equality as Strings or Runes will show they are not equal:

```
print('\u00e9' == '\u0065\u0301'); //false
print('é' == 'é'); //false, if copy/pasted from the two different representations
print('\u00e9'.runes == '\u0065\u0301'.runes); //false
```

Fair enough - that's what is expected from how Dart deals with Strings. But I had thought that the characters package was supposed to deal with issues like this. Yet when comparing the characters, it is still not equal:

```
print('\u00e9'.characters == '\u0065\u0301'.characters); //false
```

...even though it recognizes both as a single character (i.e. characters.length is 1). Therefore I'm not sure if there's a way to test for equality when accounting for multiple ways of building these grapheme clusters. Any ideas?

Comment: Awfully late, but I think what you are looking for is Unicode Equivalence / Normalization Forms. 1.  (Wikipedia): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence 2. (unicode.org): https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/unorm_dart e.g. `unorm.nfc('\u0065\u0301') == '\u00e9'` ?