# Flutter how to compare two same Japanese strings which is differently encoded

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, utf-8, cjk

I have a function in Flutter which gets two strings as parameters and returns the corresponding data from a converted csv file. String 1 is somewhere in the first row, and string 2 is somewhere in the first column of the csv, and I want to obtain the two indexes so that I can return whatever is in that specific row and column.

```
  Future<String> getData(String ward, String trashType) async {
    final csvString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.csv');
    final csvData = CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);

    final wardIndex = csvData[0].indexOf(ward);

    final trashRow = csvData.firstWhere((row) => row[0] == trashType);

    final data = trashRow[wardIndex];

    return data;
  }
```

I was trying ages to figure out why the firstWhere method was giving me an error, only to find that the two strings looked exactly the same but are encoded differently:

```
trashType
UTF-8-decoded:少量の木くず、葉・Twigs,Leaves
UTF-8-encoded: \xE5\xB0\x91\xE9\x87\x8F\xE3\x81\xAE\xE6\x9C\xA8\xE3\x81\x8F\xE3\x81\x9A\xE3\x80\x81\xE8\x91\x89\xE3\x83\xBB\x54\x77\x69\x67\x73\x2C\x4C\x65\x61\x76\x65\x73

String in row[0]
UTF-8-decoded:少量の木くず、葉・Twigs,Leaves
UTF-8-encoded: \xE5\xB0\x91\xE9\x87\x8F\xE3\x81\xAE\xE6\x9C\xA8\xE3\x81\x8F\xE3\x81\x99\xE3\x82\x99\xE3\x80\x81\xE8\x91\x89\xE3\x83\xBB\x54\x77\x69\x67\x73\x2C\x4C\x65\x61\x76\x65\x73
```

Is there a way to ensure that the strings will be equal when they are the 'same'? I was looking into Unicode normalization but couldn't figure out how to implement it. Also I am a beginner at Flutter so any improvements to the code is appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Testing unicode grapheme cluster equality in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64094438/), but unfortunately that has no answers.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/unorm_dart